# How do i stop a PDF being included in the page count in latex?

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages, roman-numerals

I'm constructing a thesis by paper submission and I would like to include a PDF article submission without including these pages in the page count.

The numbering within the PDF is Arabic, so the pages *before* and *after* must be roman.

Currently I have:

- An unnumbered title page
- Pages numbered **i** to **iv** before `\includepdf{Paper.pdf}`
- The included pdf, already numbered **1** to **28**.
- Pages numbered **xxxv** to **xxxviii** (I would like this to be **vii** to **x**)

I have tried:

```
\pagestyle{empty}  

\includepdf{Paper.pdf}

\pagebreak

\pagestyle{plain}  

\setcounter{page}{7}  

\pagenumbering{roman}
```

However, this just starts the roman numbering from 1 again... Other variations seem to eliminate the post-PDF numbering altogether.

Based on answers to other similar questions I assume I'm not far off, but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Try moving the `\setcounter` instruction *after* the `\pagenumbering{roman}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to look at what `\pagenumbering` actually does in order to understand why (from the [LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co)):

```
\def\pagenumbering#1{%
  \global\c@page \@ne % <---------------------------- 1
  \gdef\thepage{\csname @#1\endcsname \c@page}}% <--- 2
```

Note how `\pagenumbering{<scheme>}` does *two* things:

1. Globally (re)sets the page number counter `\c@page` to 1;
2. Globally (re)defines `\thepage` to be a representation of the page counter according to `<type>`. Here `<scheme>` is defined as a macro `\@<scheme>`. So, `\pagenumbering{roman}` results in `\@roman`.

Your approach sets the page number to 7 via

```
\setcounter{page}{7}
```

but this is reset to 1 with a call to

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
```

You should just be able to drop the `\pagenumbering` call as `\includepdf{...}` should include the document without setting anything in the header/footer. However, if that doesn't suit you, you can always be verbose with

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{7}
```